# overfull hbox when I insert hline

Tags: table-of-contents, rules, tocloft

I've got an issue related to table of contents. I want a horizontal line before each section, so I put

```
    \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{
\hline
%other stuff that I need
}
```

This is perfect in terms of what I see, but I get a warning because (I guess) the compiler expects to find `\hline` within a table. So I replaced it with

```
line(1,0){length}
```

The problem now is that if length is long enough (I need the line to arrive on top of the page number), I get an overfull hbox.

Any idea? I already searched related problems with no luck.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing only spare information. However I guess you are looking for `\hrulefill`. So you modification can be:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\hrulefill\par\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip\bfseries}
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for (I had tried with \hrulefill only without success)